# Stripe Payouts as an Escrow emulation

Tags: php, symfony, stripe-payments

I'm trying to emulate the Escrow system using Stripe Payouts. Actually, there is no escrow in Stripe now but in [this Q/A article](https://www.quora.com/Does-Stripe-provide-an-escrow-facility-that-allows-users-to-authorize-payments-that-would-be-taken-out-at-some-time-in-the-future) I've received an advice to use Payouts for this case.
The official documentation covers Payouts not so good. The best I found is [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_payout).
The idea is to send payments to user's card. 
I'm building the web-application using Angular 4 and Symfony Framework 3.2. This part was server-side executed, so the PHP code is the following:

```
public function payToCardAction()
{
    $apiKey = $this->getParameter('stripe_secret');
    Stripe::setApiKey($apiKey);

    try{
        Payout::create(
            array(
                'amount'      => 400,
                'currency'    => 'gbp',
                'description' => 'Example payment',
                'source_type' => 'card',
                'destination' => preg_replace('/\s+/', '','4242 4242 4242 4242')
            )
        );
    }
    catch (Card $e){
        return new JsonResponse(
            array(
                'status' => 400,
                'message'=> 'Bad request'
            )
        );
    }
    return new JsonResponse(
        array(
            'status'   => 200,
            'message'  => 'Success'
        )
    );
}
```

I used test card (4242 4242 4242 4242) in order to send there some test money but received the following error:

```
No such external account: 4242424242424242
```

Error reference in the documentation didn't help me. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) to accept payments on behalf of third-parties and send payouts to their bank accounts (or debit cards, in the US).

I recommend you reach out to Stripe's support at https://support.stripe.com/email to explain your business model and desired flow of funds. They will help you make sure your model is supported and advise on which APIs exactly you should use.

Comment: Thank you, that helped! I attach also the official response from Stripe Support in order to help someone else who may face with the same issue:

Comment: Payouts could be used for some light weight escrow system but it only works with Connect Custom accounts:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts
Basically the users you'd be handling funds for would be represented by a Custom account and you'd be able to keep funds store in their Custom account balance for up to 90 days if you used manual payouts:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#using-manual-payouts

Comment: Custom accounts allow you to handle all the personal details that are required by authorities when managing funds for other people:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification
Regarding the error you're seeing this is because when creating manual payouts you can only pass an already stored bank account id or debit card id:
https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_payout-destination
In the case of Custom accounts you'd use our External Accounts methods to do that:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#bank-accounts